# Supporting DocBook olink in Maven Project

Tags: maven, docbook

I introduced my current project at work to DocBook for creating our user's guide. We have now split into two separate documents and I'm trying to get cross-linking between the documents working. I've got the .db files being generated now. But in doing so the html files no longer have any content (I've disabled pdf until I can get the html working). The generated xml files seem to be complete, they're just not getting transformed into html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

src.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>release</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <baseDirectory>swac-home</baseDirectory>
  <!--files>
      <file>
          <source>target/docbkx/pdf/swac-reference-manual.pdf</source>
          <fileMode>0444</fileMode>
      </file>
      <file>
          <source>target/docbkx/pdf/swac-analysts-guide.pdf</source>
          <fileMode>0444</fileMode>
      </file>
  </files-->
  <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
          <directory>target/docbkx/html</directory>
      <outputDirectory>html</outputDirectory>
          <fileMode>0444</fileMode>
      </fileSet>
      <fileSet>
          <excludes>
              <!--exclude>*.pdf</exclude-->
          </excludes>
          <directory>src/docbkx/images</directory>
          <outputDirectory>html/images</outputDirectory>
          <fileMode>0444</fileMode>
      </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>swac-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>gov.faa.ang.swac</groupId>
        <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>swac-documentation</artifactId>
    <name>SWAC Documentation</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
                <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- shared configuration -->
                    <generatedSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docbkx/generated</generatedSourceDirectory>
                    <xincludeSupported>true</xincludeSupported>
                    <paperType>Letter</paperType>
                    <fop1Extensions>1</fop1Extensions>
                    <customizationParameters>
                        <!-- additional XSLT parameters-->
                        <!--parameter>
                            <name>key</name>
                            <value>value</value>
                        </parameter-->
                    </customizationParameters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>olinkdb-bogus-guide</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <currentDocid>bogus-guide</currentDocid>
                            <includes>swac-analysts-guide.xml</includes>
                            <collectXrefTargets>only</collectXrefTargets>
                            <targetsFilename>${project.build.directory}/docbkx/generated/guide.html-target.db</targetsFilename>
                            <postProcess>
                               <!--delete file="${project.build.directory}/docbkx/generated/html/bogus-guide.html" /-->
                            </postProcess>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-html</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>olinkdb-bogus-manual</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <currentDocid>bogus-manual</currentDocid>
                            <includes>swac-reference-manual.xml</includes>
                            <collectXrefTargets>only</collectXrefTargets>
                            <targetsFilename>${project.build.directory}/docbkx/generated/manual.html-target.db</targetsFilename>
                            <postProcess>
                               <!--delete file="${project.build.directory}/docbkx/generated/html/bogus-manual.html" /-->
                            </postProcess>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-html</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>reference manual</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-html</goal>
                            <!--goal>generate-pdf</goal-->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- per execution configuration -->
                            <targetDatabaseDocument>guide.target.db</targetDatabaseDocument>
                            <xincludeSupported>true</xincludeSupported>
                            <includes>swac-reference-manual.xml</includes>
                            <draftMode>no</draftMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analysts guide</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-html</goal>
                            <!--goal>generate-pdf</goal-->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- per execution configuration -->
                            <targetDatabaseDocument>manual.target.db</targetDatabaseDocument>
                            <xincludeSupported>true</xincludeSupported>
                            <includes>swac-analysts-guide.xml</includes>
                            <draftMode>no</draftMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docbook-xml</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0-all</version>
                        <classifier>resources</classifier>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

debug output:

```
...
[DEBUG] All known ContainerDescriptorHandler components: [metaInf-services, plexus, file-aggregator, metaInf-spring]
[DEBUG] Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint: project-cache-aware
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  roleHint: project-cache-aware
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.repository.DefaultRepositoryAssembler.contextualize(DefaultRepositoryAssembler.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.contextualize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manageLifecycle(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:143)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.EntryListAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntryListAdapter.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:445)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:3006)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    ... 43 more
[DEBUG] No dependency sets specified.
[DEBUG] FileSet[html/] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
[DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\target\docbkx\html
[DEBUG] Adding file-set from directory: 'C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\target\docbkx\html'
assembly output directory is: 'html/'
[DEBUG] Adding file-set in: C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\target\docbkx\html to archive location: html/
[DEBUG] FileSet[html/images/] dir perms: -1 file perms: 107777
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
[DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\src\docbkx\images
[DEBUG] Adding file-set from directory: 'C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\src\docbkx\images'
assembly output directory is: 'html/images/'
[DEBUG] Adding file-set in: C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\src\docbkx\images to archive location: html/images/
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ssmitz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trunk\swac-users-guide\target\swac-documentation-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
```

Comment: You've hit a bug. Best to report it to the Maven project as such.